# "NetworkCommsDotNet" "expectedReturnPacketTypeStr"

Tags: c#, networking, types, client-server, packet

I am trying to figure out what string to use for "expectedReturnPacketTypeStr" in the "NetworkCommsDotNet" dll api.

Basically I'm trying to send a convermation back to the client after sending a message.

I'm using NetworkCommsDotNet since it is very easy to send messages, however when trying to get a confirmation back I need to have the "expectedReturnPacketTypeStr" for their method. I am unsure what it is asking for since my knowledge of network coding is limited.

I tried a few different strings but had no luck. Does anyone know what I am missing or can point me to the right direction. Thank you.

```
string test = NetworkComms.SendReceiveObject<string>("Message", serverIP, serverPort, expectedReturnPacketTypeStr, 2000, messageToSend);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out.

I had to have the expectedReturnPacketTypeStr be the name/header of the message and then on the server side have a 
`connection.SendObject("Confirm", "Got It");`

This way once the message was sent then it would look for the "Confirm". Makes more sense now.